# super function is returning None along with result

Tags: python, subclass, python-2.x

I have below code with parent class `Test` and subclass `MyTest` .
From outside, i am trying to access the method of the parent class instead of subclass. so i am expecting the `display` function of the parent class.
so, i use `super` function to achieve this. so far so good. but when i try to assign the return of the super function to a variable say `z`, i see it prints what i am expecting and also prints `'None'`.

```
class Test(object):
    def display(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print self.x

class MyTest(Test):
    def someother(self):
        print "i am a different method"
    def display(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print "Getting called form MyTest"



a = MyTest()
z = super(type(a), a).display(10)
print z

10
None
```

I am trying to understand why super function is  returning 'None' along with expected value

Comment: you need add `return` inside the `display` by default it is `return None`

Comment: You need a `return self.x`. Otherwise, you can `print a.x` instead.

Comment: Printing is not the same thing as *returning a result*. The default return value for any function is `None`, unless it specifically returns something different.

Comment: Note that none of this is specific to `super()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyTest.display` method does not include any `return` statement.
Therefore, `return None` is implied.
As a consequence, `z = super(type(a), a).display(10)` results in an assignment of `None` into `z`.

You need to append a `return` statement in your method, for example:

```
def display(self, x):
    self.x = x
    print "Getting called form MyTest"
    return self.x
```

Answer (score 1):

Any **callable** in python that doesn't explicitly use the `return` on them will return `None` by default.

So, to fix that just use `return` instead of just printing:

```
class Test(object):
    def display(self, x):
        self.x = x
        return self.x
```

Comment: That's not exactly true: classes are callable, although no explicit `return` statement is needed to have `Foo()` return the instance created. But I admit that this is nitpicking.

Comment: Yeah, but also they can implement __call__ that's why I chosed callable instead of function, but you are right